# Make Sylius catalog only

Tags: php, sylius

Who has experience Sylius before? Is possible to close front end purchase module to make Sylius become like catalog only? That mean user only can preview product's detail but unable to make purchase. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Somebody help me :'(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.
You would have to overwrite twig templates, routes, the checkout state machine. This may be helpful:
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/checkout.html
From the top of my head, I would go with leaving just one state (or none), but you have to play with it. I've never tried it yet. Not sure if that's all you need...

```
winzou_state_machine:
  sylius_order_checkout:
    class: "%sylius.model.order.class%"
    property_path: checkoutState
    graph: sylius_order_checkout
    state_machine_class: "%sylius.state_machine.class%"
    states:
      cart: ~
```